# How do you find which post houses in LA are union?

Tags: unions

I worked hard to get rostered on the IER and now want to focus my job search on union facilities. I know many facilities outside of the lots are union, a good amount of my friends who do work on lot were hired from facilities that were off lot but union. So, I know of a few. But how do you get the list so you can focus on these companies specifically in your job search?  Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to contact the Motion Picture Editors Guild and see if they have a list of what facilities are signatories.

Comment: I did.  But you have to be union to get the list and you have to pay $3500 to be union.  I did however get rostered and take all my required classes. All I have to do is stroke a check to get in. But I am job hunting so $3500 is a lot for me to pony right now without a guarantee of work. 